# ACF Repeater and Flexslider not working

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, flexslider

For some reason my images aren't showing and I can't seem to figure it out. I'm also getting this error when I inspect the page, $(...).onload is not a function.
Heres all the code to do with the slider maybe you can notice something wrong. Thanks

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/flexslider.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(window).onload(function() {
      $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide"
      });
    });

  </script>
</head>

<div class="conatainer-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <?php if(get_field('slider')): ?>
        <div class="flexslider">
          <ul class="slides">
            <?php while(has_sub_field('slider')): ?>
              <li><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>" alt="Welcome to StairWorld" /></li>
              <?php endwhile; ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does flexslider work with jquery 3 - it's quite old so may only work with earlier versions of jquery

Comment: according to the woocommerce site it is compatible with the latest jQuery

Comment: while loop? See my answer below.

Comment: Are you sure - it just says 1.3+ (but hasn't been updated for a very long time) and all the examples are using jquery 1. Also, I know jQuery 3 has removed a lot of stuff as support for the older browsers has been dropped

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out I had to change $(window).onload to $(document).ready

Comment: That shouldn't really make any difference - I have used many flexsliders and initiated them in the window load function, but if it works for you then that's weird

Answer (score -1):

I recommend taking a look at https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/gallery/

It is an excellent tutorial how you build this.

```
<?php 

$images = get_field('gallery');

if( $images ): ?>
    <div id="slider" class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
        <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
            <li>
                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                <p><?php echo $image['caption']; ?></p>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
            <li>
                <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Please do not forget to download and connect the flexslider files.
https://woocommerce.com/flexslider/

```
<!-- Place somewhere in the <head> of your document -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
```

Also, include this in the header:

```
<!-- Place in the <head>, after the three links -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @pete I updated the answer and copied the code from the link!